# jQuery form.validate() callback failing to execute ($.ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I've currently got an issue with a HTML form. I'm attempting to validate the form (rules are in the HTML 5 code), and then use an $.ajax call to submit it to a php script to handle. The aim is to make sure that various fields are filled before submitting, and print any additional errors (user exists, email in use, the web dev is clueless, etc) with ajax. Otherwise, if everything works, it's meant to hide the form and display a confirmation message.

With the code below, the validation works correctly, but the $.ajax call doesn't - the form's default action fires intead. However, if I comment out the validate function and its submitHandler (and their closing braces), form submission works normally. I've been smashing my head against this for a couple of days now with no luck. Any help or insight anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

This is the javascript I'm running.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Submit").click(function() {

        $("#mrf").validate({
            submitHandler: function() {
                    // Begin the submit handler function
                    var action = $("#mrf").attr('action');
                    var msg_success = '<p style="font-weight: bold;">Your registration was successful! You should receive a welcome email shortly.</p>';
                    var form_data = {
                        Surname: $("#Surname").val(),
                        First_Name: $("#FirstName").val(),
                        Other_Names: $("#OtherNames").val(),
                        Address: $("#Address").val(),
                        Suburb: $("#Suburb").val(),
                        State: $("#State").val(),
                        Postcode: $("#Postcode").val(),
                        Email: $("#Email").val(),
                        Username: $("#Username").val(),
                        INSTEP: $("#INSTEP").val(),
                        Mobile: $("#Mobile").val(),
                        Cohort: $("#Cohort").val(),
                        Academy: $("input:radio[name=Academy]:checked").val(),
                        University: $("#University").val(),
                        Program: $("#Program").val(),
                        NonUni: $("#NonUni").val(),
                        Mentoring: $("input:checkbox[name=Mentoring]:checked").val(),
                        CAS: $("input:checkbox[name=CAS]:checked").val(),
                        Motivational_Speaking: $("input:checkbox[name=MotivationalSpeaking]:checked").val(),
                        Workshops: $("input:checkbox[name=Workshops]:checked").val(),
                        Tutoring: $("input:checkbox[name=Tutoring]:checked").val(),
                        Newsletter: $("input:checkbox[name=Newsletter]:checked").val(),
                        is_ajax: 1
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: action,
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function(response) {
                            if(response == 'success')   {
                                $("#mrf-form").slideUp('slow', function() {
                                    $("#ajaxResponse").html(msg_success);
                                });
                            }
                            else    {
                                $('#ajaxResponse').html("<p class='error'>" + response + "</p>");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    // End the submit handler function      
                }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make this

```
e.preventDEfault();
```

the first line in the function

```
$("#Submit").click(function(e){});
```

this wat atleast the default submit event wont be fired;
then check for errors in all the lines above `$.ajax({` 
because if they ll have any error then javascript would discontinue to execute and default submit function will be called you can do this by using developer tools "F12"
ie. check wether all the values in the form data are being correctly filled or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've debugged the script using Firebug, and have determined that the error happens at 
    `submitHandler: function() {`

I stepped through as long as a could, and it go to this code in the jquery library
    `jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
undefined;`

At which point it ceased to execute (and the default submit function was called if I had your edits commented out). I have no idea how to fix this though, do you suppose it's a syntax error? None of the form data was passed. I'll keep looking.

Comment: glad it helped :) so this was your answer

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but it might be easier for you to use a validation plugin. I've been using this and I'm very happy, it's easy and yet extendable and it looks great on the client side and it has i18n support if you need it:

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Having said that, if you insist on doing it with your custom code, you might want to have your `submitHandler` function return `false`. You are already submitting the data and therefore you don't want the action to fire.